# Moving from Database First to Code First

Tags: c#, entity-framework

My question is similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20658549/switch-from-entity-framework-database-first-to-code-first), however I would like suggestions for my current issue:

Let's assume that my initial database before any database changes is called V1. All client's databases are based on V1.

I used EF6 Database First to generate my model based on V1. Changes were done directly in the database during development (add, update, delete tables, columns, etc...) and the model was refreshed accordingly to keep it in sync.

Now that EF7 will soon come out and it will support only Code First, I'm leaning towards moving from Database First to Code First as it's still early in application development (although lots of changes were already done to the database).

I would also like to use CF Migrations to migrate databases, initially from V1.

My problem is that my development database is not V1 anymore so I cannot use it for my initial migration on customer's databases.

Do I need to start CF again based on a V1 database and do all database changes again using Migrations?